# How do I string together c# Lambda expressions when I have a join statement in one of them

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I'm stringing/concatenating together Lambda expressions
Here is what I have.

```
var products = context.Products.Select(c => c);

if (input.DefendantId != null)
{
       products = products
          .Where(p => p.DefendantId == input.DefendantId);
}
```

but now, the DefendantId has been removed from the Product table, so I need to add a join clause on a transaltion table (ProductDefendant), while still returning a

> `IQueryable<Product>`

The ProductDefendant table has both the ProductId and DefendantId in it.

so something like this below, but I'm not sure how to get the last part that uses the where clause because the `p.ProductDefendant` is a `List<ProductDefendant>`

```
if (input.DefendantId != null)
{
    products = products
        .Join(context.ProductDefendant, 
        p => p.Id, 
        pd => pd.ProductId, 
        (p, pd) => new Product())
        .Where(p => p.ProductDefendant.DefendantId == input.DefendantId);
}
```

I wrote it as a linq, but I want to use Lambda expressions instead.

Here is the linq

```
            products =
                from p in products
                join pd in context.ProductDefendant
                    on p.Id equals pd.ProductId
                where pd.DefendantId == input.DefendantId
                select p;
```

and then at the very end I can't seem to get the 'DefendantCode' which is a join on the ProductDefendant and the Defendant

```
var productsVM = products.Select(c => new GetProductsReturnViewModel
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            ProductName = c.ProductName,
            DefendantCode = c.ProductDefendants.First().Defendant.DefendantCode // only gets teh first, not the correct code
        });
```

Comment: Create a navigation property `Product.ProductDefendant` and it will all become very simple.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you need to first select both `Product` and `ProductDefendant` in your `Join`, and then `Select` just the `Product` part after the `Where` filters the results:

```
products = products
    .Join(context.ProductDefendant,
        p => p.Id, 
        pd => pd.ProductId,
        (p, pd) => new {Product = p, ProductDefendant = pd})
    .Where(joined => joined.ProductDefendant.DefendantId == input.DefendantId)
    .Select(joined => joined.Product);
```

Comment: I think that's it! Let me do a quick check!

Comment: I think it works but now I'm not sure how to get the defendantCode at the very end. I'll post the last statement in my post above.

Answer (score 1):

This way should work,

```
var productsVM = products
    .Join(context.ProductDefendant,
        p => p.Id,
        pd => pd.ProductId,
        (p, pd) => new { Product = p, ProductDefendant = pd })
    .Where(joined => joined.ProductDefendant.DefendantId == input.DefendantId)
    .Select(joined => new GetProductsReturnViewModel
    {
        Id = joined.Product.Id,
        ProductName = joined.Product.ProductName,
        DefendantCode = joined.ProductDefendant.Defendant.DefendantCode
    });
```